# How Google apps domain is being set up for naked domain redirection?

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite

I've purchased a domain as part of google apps "standard" edition signup.

This is how the zone record was configured on godaddy:

```
; SOA Record
VEKSLERS.ORG.   3600    IN  SOA ns33.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net. (
                2010091700
                28800
                7200
                604800
                86400
                )

; A Records
@   3600    IN  A   216.239.32.21
@   3600    IN  A   216.239.34.21
@   3600    IN  A   216.239.36.21
@   3600    IN  A   216.239.38.21

; CNAME Records
www 3600    IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com
calendar    3600    IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com
mail    3600    IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com
start   3600    IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com
docs    3600    IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com

; MX Records
@   3600    IN  MX  10  aspmx.l.google.com
@   3600    IN  MX  20  alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
@   3600    IN  MX  20  alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
@   3600    IN  MX  30  aspmx2.googlemail.com
@   3600    IN  MX  30  aspmx3.googlemail.com
@   3600    IN  MX  30  aspmx4.googlemail.com
@   3600    IN  MX  30  aspmx5.googlemail.com

; SRV Records
_xmpp-server._tcp.@ 3600    IN  SRV 5   0   5269    xmpp-server.l.google.com
_xmpp-server._tcp.@ 3600    IN  SRV 20  0   5269    xmpp-server1.l.google.com
_xmpp-server._tcp.@ 3600    IN  SRV 20  0   5269    xmpp-server2.l.google.com
_xmpp-server._tcp.@ 3600    IN  SRV 20  0   5269    xmpp-server3.l.google.com
_xmpp-server._tcp.@ 3600    IN  SRV 20  0   5269    xmpp-server4.l.google.com
_jabber._tcp.@  3600    IN  SRV 5   0   5269    xmpp-server.l.google.com
_jabber._tcp.@  3600    IN  SRV 20  0   5269    xmpp-server1.l.google.com
_jabber._tcp.@  3600    IN  SRV 20  0   5269    xmpp-server2.l.google.com
_jabber._tcp.@  3600    IN  SRV 20  0   5269    xmpp-server3.l.google.com
_jabber._tcp.@  3600    IN  SRV 20  0   5269    xmpp-server4.l.google.com

; NS Records
@   3600    IN  NS  ns33.domaincontrol.com
@   3600    IN  NS  ns34.domaincontrol.com
```

Now, I know that google app engine does [not support "naked domains"](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=777) and indeed a forwarding is configured from vekslers.org to www.vekslers.org.

What I don't understand is how this is being setup? 
Assuming that "@" in A records means "root" (?), these configured IP's lead to Google servers, does the AppEngine team have a default redirect from foo.com to www.foo.com is foo.com is a registered Google Apps domain?

Clarifications would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it:

```
$ host vekslers.org
vekslers.org has address 216.239.32.21

$ curl -D- VEKSLERS.ORG
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.vekslers.org/
Date: Fri, 01 Oct 2010 14:27:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: ghs
Content-Length: 221
```

216.239.32.21 is owned by google, so it looks like they are emitting the redirect to www.vekslers.org.

When they say they do not handle "naked" domains I think they mean you cannot serve your site from a naked domain.  Instead you have to let them redirect the naked address to the non-naked one as they are doing above.

Comment: That's cool, can I they control to what address they will be redirecting to?

Comment: I doubt it, Google is convenient but they don't offer you a lot of flexibility on these things.  You would need to go to a more full service hosting company.